# Can an unmanaged switch slow down internet access?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have an ADSL router. 
It works fine. 
When I plug directly into it via ethernet, all is fine.
It doesn't have enough ports though, only 4. 
I bought a cheap Dlink unmanaged switch. 
When I connect to the pc > switch > router it works, but internet access is noticeably slower. When I take the switch out its back to normal.

Why?

I've tested all cables with a cable tester.
Normal network shares are fast to access.

Comment: Yes and... which ports involved are capable to run 10, 100 or 1000 MBit/s; does auto negotiation work correctly, etc etc...

Comment: Check cables to make sure they are all cat6 or above. Cheap switches usually come with cat5 cables. Check switch if it is gigabit or 10/100 Mbit

Comment: What brand and model of ADSL router do you have?

Comment: "Can a cheap unmanaged switch slow down internet access" It indeed can do that as you have just proved.

Comment: The Dlink switch has AutoMDI Crossover, but its a terrible router. Would I still need a crossover cable? I'm guessing this might be the issue?

Comment: Would an old and terrible 10/100 port on a adsl router be considered a switch? Does AutoMDI only work when both devices support it?

Comment: if it works at all (slow or fast) then the AutoMDI is working.  Try a different switch, that one may just be faulty...

Comment: Thank you for actual helping answers, to the sarcastic rest, I hope people reply the same to you when you have a question. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, cable length reports as 200meters on Intel Network Diagnostic tool. All pins report as connected with cable tester. Used another cable just to be sure and it fixed the issue. I'm guessing the cable has an intermittant break or just a bad batch. Replacing with a new cat 6 shielded cable.